# Export contacts as displayed?

Tags: export

Is there a way to export contacts (to a csv) as they are displayed without having to create a field mapping?

Comment: Note that this is a major feature request being considered for the 2020 search overhaul.

Answer (score 1):

From Search its not possible i guess unless you save the mapping and reuse it, but from report you can generate csv from the fields you have selected as to display